# Not able to install any app

Tags: apt, software-installation

Recently i am facing a strange issue that when i am trying to install anything or update  via `terminal` I am getting the following error.

```
E: The package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-80-generic needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

I have searched everywhere but couldn't find it anywhere. Screenshot attached.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: @luk3yx I don't think that it's a duplicate of that link because this question is about an issue with a Linux kernel.

Comment: @karel I assumed that different packages, including kernels, would have the same workaround. Am I incorrect?

Comment: That's not what I am concerned about. What I am concerned about is avoiding possible damage to the system that may be caused by applying crude generic package management solutions to an issue with the kernel.

Comment: There is a warning in the screenshot (you should [paste the whole output as text](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8713/why-do-people-post-screenshots-of-their-terminals) next time) telling that the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` is not in the best possible condition. Could you add the contents of this file [into your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/955985/edit)?